# Why window manager not working with modern devices

Tags: android, android-studio, android-windowmanager

`WindowManger` not working on modern devices I don't know what is reason but I got this error in logcat

`Caused by: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not valid; is your activity running?`

*Permissions*

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
```

*WindowManagerService Class*

```
public class WindowManagerService extends Service {

    WindowManager windowManager;
    RelativeLayout relativeLayout;
    WindowManager.LayoutParams params;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_test, null);
        params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_TOAST,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
        windowManager.addView(relativeLayout, params);
    }

}
```

Device number `API 28`

Before I post my problem here I searched via google about logcat message in above but all ways not working so if there any suggestions about my problem I hope you put here.

Comment: extend service dont work , 
it must but Activity

Comment: @YogeshBorhade Do you can put example ?

Comment: Oreo device require System.canDrawOverlay permission  for drawing overlay